# Netty (UDP) SSLException : Received close_notify during handskake,close channel

Tags: ssl, udp, netty

I want to write an UDP Netty Server/Client with SSL . I did it in the way similar to TCP Netty Server/Client which worked well.  But I meet an exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException:Received close_notify during handskake,close channel...
```

My netty is 3.x , SSL configure works well . Here is some code of my Udp Server and Client. Server:

```
serverBootstrap = new ConnectionlessBootstrap(
            new NioDatagramChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),maxThreads));
serverBootstrap.setOption("receiveBufferSizePredictorFactory",
            new FixedReceiveBufferSizePredictorFactory(8192));
 ChannelPipelineFactory fac = null;
 try {

        ServiceDecoder serviceProcessor = (ServiceDecoder)Class.forName(serviceDecoderName).newInstance();

        Class<? extends ChannelPipelineFactory> clazz = (Class<? extends ChannelPipelineFactory>) Class
                .forName(msgFactoryName);

        Constructor ctor = clazz.getConstructor(ChannelProcessor.class,
                ChannelGroup.class, CounterGroup.class, CounterGroupExt.class, String.class,ServiceDecoder.class,
                String.class, Integer.class, String.class, String.class, Boolean.class,Integer.class,Boolean.class,Boolean.class,Context.class);

        logger.info("Using channel processor:{}", getChannelProcessor().getClass().getName());
        fac = (ChannelPipelineFactory) ctor.newInstance(
                getChannelProcessor(), allChannels, counterGroup, counterGroupExt, "udp", serviceProcessor,
                messageHandlerName, maxMsgLength, topic, attr, filterEmptyMsg, maxConnections, isCompressed,enableSsl,context);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(
                "Simple Udp Source start error, fail to construct ChannelPipelineFactory with name {}, ex {}",
                msgFactoryName, e);
        stop();
        throw new FlumeException(e.getMessage());
    }

    serverBootstrap.setPipelineFactory(fac);

    try {
        if (host == null) {
            nettyChannel = serverBootstrap
                    .bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
        } else {
            nettyChannel = serverBootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(host,
                    port));
        }
```

Pipeline in Server:

```
 if(enableSsl) {
        cp.addLast("ssl", sslInit());
    }
if (processor != null) {

        try {
            Class<? extends SimpleChannelHandler> clazz = (Class<? extends SimpleChannelHandler>) Class
                    .forName(messageHandlerName);

            Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor(
                    ChannelProcessor.class, ServiceDecoder.class, ChannelGroup.class,
                    CounterGroup.class, CounterGroupExt.class, String.class, String.class,
                    Boolean.class, Integer.class, Integer.class, Boolean.class);

            SimpleChannelHandler messageHandler = (SimpleChannelHandler) ctor
                    .newInstance(processor, serviceProcessor, allChannels,
                            counterGroup, counterGroupExt, topic, attr,
                            filterEmptyMsg, maxMsgLength, maxConnections, isCompressed);

            cp.addLast("messageHandler", messageHandler);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
       if (this.protocolType.equalsIgnoreCase(ConfigConstants.UDP_PROTOCOL)) {
            cp.addLast("execution", executionHandler);
        }
```

client:

```
private ConnectionlessBootstrap clientBootstrap;
    clientBootstrap = new ConnectionlessBootstrap(
            new NioDatagramChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));
    clientBootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {
        @Override
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
            ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();

            pipeline.addLast("sslHandler", sslInit());
            pipeline.addLast("orderHandler",new ExecutionHandler(
                    new OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(cores * 2,
                            1024 * 1024, 1024 * 1024)));
            return pipeline;
        }
    });
```

Two function to send message in the client:

```
public void sendMessage(byte[] data) {
    ChannelBuffer buffer = ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(data);
    sendMessage(buffer);
}

public void sendMessage(ChannelBuffer buffer) {
    Random random = new Random();
    Channel channel = channelList.get(random.nextInt(channelList.size()));
    if(!channel.isConnected()){
        channel.close();
        ChannelFuture cf = clientBootstrap
                .connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port));
        if(cf.awaitUninterruptibly(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)){
            channel = cf.getChannel();
        }else {
            channelList.remove(channel);
            return;
        }
    }
    ChannelFuture future = channel.write(buffer);
    if(!future.awaitUninterruptibly(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)){
        logger.warn("send failed!{}",future.getCause());
    }else {
        sendCnt.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

I suspect whether UDP Netty Server/Client support SSL.   Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: I suspect so too. I'm astonished you got as far as you did. What peer were you communicating with?

Comment: @EJP I have been reading the flume code for a few days ,I just want to encrypt the data transported from netty client to server(i.e. flume source),and have done with the TCP ,but when I tried UDP,it failed. Can you explain why UDP can't support SSL? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I didn't say anything about UDP not being able to support SSL. I was agreeing with your comment that maybe *Netty* doesn't do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

UDP does not guarantee the order of packets, as opposed to TCP, since there is no session. Thus, during the SSL negotiation, there could be an issue, depending on the order of the UDP packets.

According to what I read, you might have a look to [DTLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram_Transport_Layer_Security) which suppose to add a sort of order control in UDP packets, but lot of SSL libraries do not support it.

Since Netty only implements [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security), it may not work with UDP.

Comment: Is there any way to use DTLS with netty ,or any examples?

Comment: As far as I know, I don't know any implementation of DTLS using Netty. But following the spec and taking the TLS implementation of Netty as a start, it should not be so complicated, I hope...